# Reshape dataframe into several columns based on date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to rearrange my example dataframe (df.csv) below based on the date column. Each row represents an hour's data for instance for both dates 2002-01-01 and 2002-01-02, there is 5 rows respectively, each representing 1 hour.

```
date,symbol
2002-01-01,A
2002-01-01,A
2002-01-01,A
2002-01-01,B
2002-01-01,A
2002-01-02,B
2002-01-02,B
2002-01-02,A
2002-01-02,A
2002-01-02,A
```

My expected output is as below .

```
date,hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4, hour5
2002-01-01,A,A,A,B,A
2002-01-02,B,B,A,A,A
```

I have tried the below as explained here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html, but it doesnt work in my case because the symbol column contains duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

pivoted = df.pivot(index="date", columns="symbol")
print(pivoted)
```

The data does not have the timestamps but only the date. However, each row for the same date represents an hourly interval, for instance the output could also be represented as below:

```
date,01:00, 02:00, 03:00, 04:00, 05:00
2002-01-01,A,A,A,B,A
2002-01-02,B,B,A,A,A
```

where the hour1 represent 01:00, hour2 represent 02:00...etc

Comment: can you provide a real example with the time as well?

Comment: I have adited the question with some more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the correct `pivot` approach, but you were missing a column 'time', so let's split the datetime into date and time:

```py
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = s.dt.date
df['time'] = s.dt.time
df2 = df.pivot(index='date', columns='time', values='symbol')
```

output:

```
time       01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00
date                                                   
2002-01-01        A        A        A        B        A
2002-01-02        B        B        A        A        A
```

Alternatively for having a HH:MM time, use `df['time'] = s.dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

used input:

```
date,symbol
2002-01-01 01:00,A
2002-01-01 02:00,A
2002-01-01 03:00,A
2002-01-01 04:00,B
2002-01-01 05:00,A
2002-01-02 01:00,B
2002-01-02 02:00,B
2002-01-02 03:00,A
2002-01-02 04:00,A
2002-01-02 05:00,A
```

##### not time as input!

If really you have no time in the input dates and need to 'invent' increasing ones, you could use `groupby.cumcount`:

```py
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.groupby('date').cumcount(), format='%H').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df2 = df.pivot(index='date', columns='time', values='symbol')
```

output:

```
time       01:00 02:00 03:00 04:00 05:00
date                                    
2002-01-01     A     A     A     B     A
2002-01-02     B     B     A     A     A
```

---

For each entry as an hour:

```
k = df.groupby("date").cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd("hour")
out = df.pivot_table('symbol','date',k,aggfunc=min)
print(out)

           hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4 hour5
date                                    
2002-01-01     A     A     A     B     A
2002-01-02     B     B     A     A     A
```

Comment: with `s.dt.time` you assume that the information about hours and minutes is in the data right ? because when I run the code with the example df, the whole `time` column is just 0's

Comment: @Rabinzel yes, I tried to ask OP to give a full example. I'll update the post. Otherwise we're just "inventing" the times (which OP should explicit if this is the case)

Comment: @Rabinzel I added an alternative should there really be no time

Comment: Thank you. Under the For each entry as an hour solution:, the columns are ordered as follows: hour1 hour10 hour11 hour12 hour13 hour14 hour15 hour2 hour3 hour4 hour5 hour6 hour7 hour8 hour9. How can I ensure that the order is hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4 hour5 hour6 hour7 hour8 hour9 hour10 hour11 hour12 hour13 hour14 hour15

Comment: You can use `natsort`, or set `k` to `df.groupby("date").cumcount().add(1).astype(str).zfill(2).radd("hour")`

Comment: zfill gives an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'zfill'

Comment: Sorry `df.groupby("date").cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2).radd("hour")`

Answer (score 1):

I'd have an approach for you, I guess it not the most elegant way since I have to rename both index and columns but it does the job.

```py
new_cols = ['01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00']
df1 = df.loc[df['date']=='2002-01-01', :].T.drop('date').set_axis(new_cols, axis=1).set_axis(['2002-01-01'])
df2 = df.loc[df['date']=='2002-01-02', :].T.drop('date').set_axis(new_cols, axis=1).set_axis(['2002-01-02'])

result = pd.concat([df1,df2])

print(result)

Output:

                01:00   02:00   03:00   04:00   05:00
2002-01-01      A       A       A       B       A
2002-01-02      B       B       A       A       A
```